# How to make Recaptcha work with QWebView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, recaptcha, qwebview

I'm trying to get PyQt4 to view a web-page that requires a captcha to work, but it says that the browser is unsupported. Here is a screenshot of the message:

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: As the [supported browser](https://support.google.com/recaptcha/answer/6223828?hl=en) link makes clear, webkit is not supported. However, since webengine is based on chrome, I suggest you upgrade to pyqt5 and try using that instead.

Comment: Are you sure there isnt another way? I really don’t want to recode everything to work with PyQt5. If not that’s ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by [modifying the user-agent string](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#userAgentForUrl) to include one of the supported browsers:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

class WebPage(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def userAgentForUrl(self, url):
        return super(WebPage, self).userAgentForUrl(url) + ' Chrome'

class Window(QtWebKit.QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setPage(WebPage(self))
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo'))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 600, 900)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: While this makes the error go away, I get stuck in an endless loop of CAPTCHA images, each one saying "Please try again".  I've tried chrome and safari user agents.